# get the url file by name of image

Tags: wordpress

Hi everyone I have several image in my media folder in wordpress

when a save a new image Wordpress save like year/month/name.png

```
/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/matt.png
```

It is possible find the image by name and return the url File like this?

```
wp-content/uploads/2011/01/
```

I am using this

```
    <?php $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $upload_dir['baseurl']; ?>/<?php echo $precontent; ?>.png " class="attachment-post-thumbnail">
```

where `$precontent` is the name of image and  `$upload_dir['baseurl'];`

return /wp-content/uploads but I need the year and month of this image
so I have /wp-content/uploads/matt.png

any idea?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're trying to get the full path of the attachment think that an attachment is just post with `post_type` = 'attachment'. That means you can query for them by name. Also, note that posts have unique slugs. So `matt.png` will have the slug `matt` :)

```
function get_attachment_url_by_slug( $slug ) {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'name' => sanitize_title($slug),
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
  );
  $_header = get_posts( $args );
  $header = $_header ? array_pop($_header) : null;
  return $header ? wp_get_attachment_url($header->ID) : '';
}
```

And then you just have to do the following:

`$header_url = get_attachment_url_by_slug('matt');`

which will return the full path of your file.

Note that `sanitize_title();` will auto-transform your name into a slug. So if you uploaded a file with the name. `Christmas is coming.png`, wordpress would have designated it a slug like `christmas-is-coming`. And if you use `sanitize_title('Christmas is coming');` the result would also be `christmas-is-coming` and after that you can get the full url. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database query looking at the wp_posts table, filtering rows with post_type = 'attachment', optionally post_mime_type like 'image/%' and a guid like "%/$precontent"

You will have to take care of situations where there is:

```
/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/matt.png
/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/matt.png
```

The full URL of the image is found in the column GUID. You can parse it out and get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment', 
'post_status' => 'inherit',
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
's' => 'image_name.jpg'
```

);
$query_images = new WP_Query( $args );

echo $query_images->post->guid;