# WordPress - how to get uploaded image by filename?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-4.3

How can I get the image that I upload to my media collection - by the image name?

For instance I upload an image called `apple.jpg` and now I want to get this dynamically without hard-coding its url.

So that I can do something like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_uploaded_image_url_by_name('apple');?>" />
```

Is it possible?

And better if I can get the info of this image in an array:

```
array(
   'src' => xxx,
   'alt' => 'xxx',
   'title' => 'xxx'
)
```

Any ideas?

I have tried with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470853/get-the-url-file-by-name-of-image) but it does not seem to work:

Comment: is that image a post_thumbnail or ?

Comment: no it is not uploaded to a post. it is uploaded to the media and i want to place this image everywhere on my template. does this make sense?

Comment: Well, did u use WordPress media uploader when you upload this image / s ?

Comment: yes I did. I use the media uploader - directly.

Comment: it is an unattached image.

Comment: i just added my answer but, feel so bad about my bad English (: I hope it make sense for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105624/discussion-between-fatih-toprak-and-teelou).

Answer (score 1):

```
wp_handle_upload
```

Okay, if you want to **get some meta datas of that image**, **should know uploaded ID**. (It means attachment_id) If u know its so simple When you use, this Function ;

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload

It works, for getting uploaded item ID.

```
wp_get_attachment_metadata
```

Another way, If you know that medias attachment_id u can grab all metadata about it.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata

Comment: thanks for the answer! but how can I know the id of the image?

Comment: its so simple too.. Just click Media and click your upload. Adress bar gaves your uploaded file ID.

http://i.imgur.com/na1xEmA.png

Comment: sorry, just found how to get the id from the media. thanks

Comment: nice. happy WordPress.

Comment: the problem with the id is that I have to hard code the id in my template and I need to change the image from time to time.

Comment: okay.there is another option too. Just use first method. wp_handle_upload. Or you can try some free theme options framework for handle uploading. https://github.com/syamilmj/Options-Framework

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105625/discussion-between-fatih-toprak-and-teelou).